# Scrolling div inside a div appear over div with higher z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

https://jsfiddle.net/09rcqwdf/1/

The *sidebar* has a higher `z-index`. The *container* `.main` has `overflow: none,` the `div` inside it has `overflow: scroll` but for some reason when you drag the text it thinks its over the `.scrolling` `div` when in fact its over the *sidebar* `div`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#fafafa">
  <style>
    body,
    html {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #content {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .main {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 300px;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .scroll-container {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      overflow: scroll;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .scrolling {
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 2;
      width: 3500px;
      height: 4000px
    }
    
    .sidebar {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #5555;
      overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 100000;
      width: 300px;
      bottom: 0;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="scroll-container">
        <div class="scrolling">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div>
        <div class="drag">Drag</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"><\/script>')
  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.scrolling').droppable({
      tolerance: 'pointer',
      accept: '.drag',
      drop(event, ui) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(ui);
        if (ui.helper.hasClass('cancelled')) {
          return;
        }
      },
    });
    $('.drag').draggable({
      helper() {
        const $helper = $('<div></div>');
        $helper.text('drag');
        return $helper.clone().addClass('dragged-component-helper');
      },
      start() {},
      stop(event, ui) {
        ui.helper[0].remove();
      },
      cursorAt: {
        left: 0,
        top: 5,
      },
      cancelOnEscape: true,
      appendTo: '#content',
      disabled: false,
      distance: 0,
      revert: 'invalid',
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Fixed up your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3gn57quj/ Navigate to https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3gn57quj//show for Mobile testing.

Comment: Thanks, the problem still exists though

Answer (score 2):

First thing I noticed is your `helper` callback was configured incorrectly, you had:

```
$('.drag').draggable({
  helper() {
    const $helper = $('<div></div>');
    $helper.text('drag');
    return $helper.clone().addClass('dragged-component-helper');
  },
  start() {
  },
```

Since you're defining an Object, you need to have the keyname, a colon, and then the function. Example:

```
$('.drag').draggable({
  helper: function() {
    const $helper = $('<div></div>');
    $helper.text('drag');
    return $helper.clone().addClass('dragged-component-helper');
  },
  start: () => {
  },
```

This may have been causing various initialization issues for your draggable and I am surprised it did not appear as an error in your console.

In regards to the drag action, I think this will also be cleared up by the correction.

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3gn57quj/10/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $('.scrolling').droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    accept: '.drag',
    drop(event, ui) {
      if (ui.helper.hasClass('cancelled')) {
        return false;
      }
      $(this).append(ui.helper.clone().css({
        left: (ui.offset.left - $(".sidebar").width()) + "px",
        top: ui.offset.top + "px"
      }));
    },
  });
  $('.drag').draggable({
    helper: function() {
      return $("<div>", {
        class: "drag component"
      }).html("drag");
    },
    stop(event, ui) {
      ui.helper[0].remove();
    },
    cursorAt: {
      left: 0,
      top: 5,
    },
    cancelOnEscape: true,
    appendTo: '#content',
    disabled: false,
    distance: 0,
    revert: 'invalid',
  });
});
```

Comment: It is a shorthand for a function assigned to the method's name that the console didn't shown any error message, start from ECMAScript 2015.

Comment: @RachChen then would it be `helper: () => {}` if it was shorthand?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `z-index` issue, I believe You can either

- set in Your CSS:

  ```
   .scrolling {
     background-color: transparent;
   }
  ```

  and use the `background-color` of the `scroll-container`
- or simply raise a little bit the `z-index` of the `draggable`
  (preferred solution):

  ```
   .drag {
     z-index: 10;
   }
  ```
- or maybe set the inline style in Your helper function:

  ```
   return $('<div style="z-index: 10;">', {
  ```

Finally, I believe You don't even need to raise so much the `z-index` of the `sidebar`, You can quietly avoid that

```
z-index: 100000
```

---

I strongly believe You may need also to change: `ui.helper[0].remove();` to: `ui.helper.remove();`

---

As a bonus, to correctly position the `draggable` I believe the simplest solution will be to get the scroll position of the closest [scrollable container](https://api.jqueryui.com/scrollParent/):

```
$(function() {
  $('.scrolling').droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    accept: '.drag',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.helper.hasClass('cancelled')) {
        return false;
      }
      var container = $(event.target).scrollParent();
      $(this).append(ui.helper.clone().css({
        left: (ui.offset.left + container.scrollLeft()- $(".sidebar").width()) + "px",
        top: (ui.offset.top + container.scrollTop()) + "px"
      }));
    }
  });
  $('.drag').draggable({
    helper: function() {
      return $("<div>", {
        class: "drag component"
      }).html("drag");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.remove();
    },
    cursorAt: {left: 0, top: 5},
    cancelOnEscape: true,
    appendTo: '#content',
    disabled: false,
    distance: 0,
    revert: 'invalid'
  });
});
```

---

Moreover, please note: [Twisty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463319/twisty)'s remark is correct, in latest Firefox and Chrome Your snippet works, but a brief test in some other browsers raises below error:

> Expected: ':'

Answer (score 0):

It does **not** think it’s over the `.scrolling` `div`. It it just that the `.scrolling` `div` is transparent and you can see “through” it. To see what I am saying, add a background color to your `.scrolling` `div`, which will prevent you to see what is happening behind it.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#fafafa">
  <style>
    body,
    html {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #content {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .main {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 300px;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .scroll-container {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      overflow: scroll;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .scrolling {
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 2;
      width: 3500px;
      height: 4000px;
      background: orange; <!-- Background Color to prevent transparency -->
    }

    .sidebar {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #5555;
      overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 100000;
      width: 300px;
      bottom: 0;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="scroll-container">
        <div class="scrolling">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div>
        <div class="drag">Drag</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"><\/script>')

  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.scrolling').droppable({
      tolerance: 'pointer',
      accept: '.drag',
      drop(event, ui) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(ui);
        if (ui.helper.hasClass('cancelled')) {
          return;
        }
      },
    });
    $('.drag').draggable({
      helper() {
        const $helper = $('<div></div>');
        $helper.text('drag');
        return $helper.clone().addClass('dragged-component-helper');
      },
      start() {},
      stop(event, ui) {
        ui.helper[0].remove();
      },
      cursorAt: {
        left: 0,
        top: 5,
      },
      cancelOnEscape: true,
      appendTo: '#content',
      disabled: false,
      distance: 0,
      revert: 'invalid',
    });

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to restrict the dragging between the sidebar only.

For that you need to provide option for **containment** in **draggable** function. Which will block the movement of drag.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#fafafa">
  <style>
    body,
    html {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #content {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .main {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 300px;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .scroll-container {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      overflow: scroll;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .scrolling {
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 2;
      width: 3500px;
      height: 4000px
    }

    .sidebar {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #5555;
      overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 100000;
      width: 300px;
      bottom: 0;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="scroll-container">
        <div class="scrolling">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div>
        <div class="drag">Drag</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"><\/script>')
  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.scrolling').droppable({
      tolerance: 'pointer',
      accept: '.drag',
      drop(event, ui) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(ui);
        if (ui.helper.hasClass('cancelled')) {
          return;
        }
      },
    });
    $('.drag').draggable({
    containment: ".sidebar",
      helper() {
        const $helper = $('<div></div>');
        $helper.text('drag');
        return $helper.clone().addClass('dragged-component-helper');
      },
      start() {},
      stop(event, ui) {
        ui.helper[0].remove();
      },
      cursorAt: {
        left: 0,
        top: 5,
      },
      cancelOnEscape: true,
      appendTo: '#content',
      disabled: false,
      distance: 0,
      revert: 'invalid',
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```